# Mobile Chrome App and mediaGalleries API

Tags: android, google-chrome, cordova, google-chrome-app, cordova-chrome-app

I'm building a media-player as a packaged chrome app and I would like to port it to a  mobile chrome app using cordova.

According to this site (https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/blob/master/docs/APIStatus.md) the mediaGalleries API is not yet supported. Does any one know if, and in that case when, it is planed to be suported?

Manny thanks!

Comment: I imagine it would be better to ask this over one of the Google Groups, as nobody except the Chrome developers can answer that.

Comment: Yes but we lurk here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This API is on our backlog.  I've [filed an issue to track it specifically](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/issues/170), where you can go comment to get updates on progress and/or report your use case so we can make sure to address it.

I've also [filed an issue to document our API Roadmap](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/issues/171) so you can know these answers in the future.

Our current short-term work items for the `cca` team are: bundling a modern chrome-based webview alongside your application (crosswalk), enabling an awesome rapid development workflow using a [mobile chrome app harness](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/chrome-app-harness), and polishing the existing plugins.

We'll probably start knocking off implementing more APIs again in the coming months.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm looking forward to it!